# EXPO - connect ECONNREFUSED - Connecting to Metro bundler failed

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I’ve been having this issue for quite a long time now, I’ve seen a lot of people asking for the same problem here, tried everything but still doesn’t work.

I’ve tried uninstalling node, expo-cli, deleting .expo, closing all local ports, but it just keeps showing this error. Here’s the full log of the erro:
ps. I’m using Mac and I used to have flutter installed, don’t know if that can cause any possible errors.

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'start' ]
2 info using npm@6.13.4
3 info using node@v12.14.1
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle @~prestart: @
6 info lifecycle @~start: @
7 verbose lifecycle @~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle @~start: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/Users/lucas/Desktop/Coding/ReactNative/Project/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/lucas/Desktop/flutter/flutter/bin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:~/.dotnet/tools:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:/Users/lucas/.npm-global/bin:/Users/lucas/.npm-global/bin
9 verbose lifecycle @~start: CWD: /Users/lucas/Desktop/Coding/ReactNative/Project
10 silly lifecycle @~start: Args: [ '-c', 'expo start' ]
11 silly lifecycle @~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle @~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: @ start: `expo start`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:223:5)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:223:5)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5)
14 verbose pkgid @
15 verbose cwd /Users/lucas/Desktop/Coding/ReactNative/Project
16 verbose Darwin 18.7.0
17 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
18 verbose node v12.14.1
19 verbose npm  v6.13.4
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error @ start: `expo start`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the @ start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

When I enter my localhost, it shows the normal metro page, but after ~5 seconds the page goes black and the message **Connecting to Metro bundler failed.** is shown.

Does anyone know how to solve this??

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this thread is still open or not but I faced a similar problem and I have resolved it with a few simple steps:

1. You can cut the .expo file and paste it into any other dummy
   file not present in the app directory.
2. Then after relocating the .expo folder, reopen your terminal and then do an npm start
   at the same as done previously.

As you can see in line number 23, it says it is not a problem with npm so it is
not logical to uninstall and reinstall Nodejs and npm. The line further says that there is additional logging output which mostly refers to the .expo file. Also do check if your connection over the internet is working fine and stable or not. It did work for me when I switched from a mobile hotspot to wifi.